# jQuery Validation plugin not catching errors

Tags: jquery, validation

Today is my first attempt at using the jQuery Validation plugin.  My form is for validating GPS coordinates.

Here are my rules and messages:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // validate form when called
    var validator =$("#box-registration").validate({
        rules: {
            latitude: {
                min: 0,
                max: 90,
                number: true
                },

            longitude {
                min: 0,
                max: 180,
                number: true
                },

            geo_dms {
                min: 0,
                max: 59,
                number: true
                }
            },
        messages: {
            latitude: "Latitude must be between 0 and 90",
            longitude: "Longitude must be between 0 and 180",
            geo_dms: "Degree minutes and seconds must be between 0 and 59"
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is part of the form I am trying to validate. I am trying to apply validation to the elements "geo-lat-dd" and "geo-lon-dd":

```
        <div id="geo-format-dd">
            <dl>
            <dt><label class="labelstandard">Latitude</label></dt>
            **<dd><input  id="geo-lat-dd" name="geo-lat-dd" type="text" class="latitude textinput100 nonewrow"/></dd>**
            <dd class="nonewrow">
                <input type="radio" name="latDD" id="latDDN" checked="checked" value="N" class="nonewrow" /><label class="nonewrow" for="latDDN">N</label>
                <input type="radio" name="latDD" id="latDDS" value="S" class="nonewrow" /><label class="nonewrow" for="latDDS">S</label>
            </dd>
            </dl>

            <dl class="newrow">
            <dt><label class="labelstandard">Longitude</label></dt>
            **<dd><input id="geo-lon-dd" name="geo-lon-dd" type="text" class="longitude textinput100 nonewrow" /></dd>**
            <dd class="nonewrow">
                <input type="radio" name="lonDD" id="latDDW" checked="checked" value="W" class="nonewrow" /><label class="nonewrow" for="lonDDW">W</label>
            </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
```

The two elements have classes "latitude" and "longitude" applied, and my Validation plugin rules include those classes (there are also fields for degrees-minutes-seconds so I'm trying to re-use the classes instead of using IDs).

No error messages appear when I validate the form with values like 9999 in the fields. Using Firebug, I have stepped through and confirmed the validation code is running, but it returns no exceptions.

In the rules, I have also tried putting a dot in front of the selectors, which crashed the page, and also enclosing it in quotes with a period, like ".latitude"

Can someone please point me in the right direction to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. You are calling `validate` on the selector `#box-registration` which doesn't exist in your sample markup.
2. Your `rules` options should be keyed on the form element names.  The documentation isn't clear on this; they seem to imply that the rules can automatically match base on class names, but I don't think that can be done in the way you are attempting.
3. Your JavaScript has some syntax errors.  Specifically, you're missing colons in the rules object.

I've created [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaSRR/) to show validation working with these corrections.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I guess have been working too many 12-hour days recently, to make mistakes like missing colons and not posting relevant portions of my code (#box-registration does exist in my file).  I'll try to integrate your suggestions into my code.

Comment: I was able to test your suggestion, and it works. Thank you. Interestingly, I found that the messages can be assigned via CSS classes, but as you said the rules seem to need to be assigned by element ID.

Comment: Revising my earlier comment - it actually did *not* show my messages via CSS classes. It was just that my custom messages were so close to the default I didn't notice the difference.